# How to change href of links within multiple instances of an element with jQuery depending on the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's an example element that appears multiple times on a page

```
<td class=" market all">
    <a href="linktosomesite?param=123" target="_blank">123</a>
</td>
```

The other elements change the param so other links may look like

```
<td class=" market all">
    <a href="linktosomesite?param=456" target="_blank">456</a>
</td>
```

I'm looking for a way to use jQuery (because it's already there on the site and used for other stuff) to change the link but keep the param. So the first example would look like this

```
<td class=" market all">
    <a href="otherurl?param=123" target="_blank">123</a>
</td>
```

I would prefer to not just replace the URL part but read either the param or the text that is linked and then use it to put the new URL in there.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: And the problem is? Grab the links, get the text, build the new href, change the href -> done - [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: The title mentions multiple classes, where is that explained in the question?

Comment: @Barmar my bad, it was just bad language. Tried to rephrase the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to replace `linktosomesite` to `otherurl` keeping other params same.

```
$(".market a").attr("href", function(){
    var param = this.innerHTML;
    return "linktosomesite?param="+param;
});
```

Comment: @Andreas yea missed that. My Bad. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".market a").attr("href", function(){
        jQuery(this).attr("href", "otherurl?"+ jQuery(this).attr("href").split("?").pop());
    })
```

Comment: Check the documentation of [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). You're using it wrong.